# Why does the turtle module in Python appear to have a screen attribute when trying to access it results in an attribute error?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, traceback

The following is a script attempting to draw a turtle graphic using the Python `turtle` module.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.screen()

alex = turtle.Turtle()

alex.forward(50)

alex.left(90)

alex.forward(30)

wn.mainloop()
```

At runtime, the script produces the following traceback (with generic path to script).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "</path/to/script>.py", line <number>, in <module>
    wn = turtle.screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'screen'
```

It appears that the `turtle` module has a `screen` attribute in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html). That being the case, why does this `AttributeError` occur?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your post is not a question but this is a Question and Answer forum. Please convert your post into a specific and answerable question.

Comment: Here's a tip: You can put your code around triple reverse quotes (top left of your keyboard) to nicely format it.

Comment: Please explain your code. Try to explain what it is that you're trying to do. For example, are you encountering a particular error?

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting this error wn = turtle.screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'screen'

Comment: You have a simple typo. ```turtle.Screen()``` will work. Please update your question.

Comment: If you're looking for further tips on writing good questions on StackOverflow, I recommend reading this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually, to correct myself, StackOverflow is a Question and Answer site, but officially it is not considered a forum.

Comment: Have you installed turtle library or imported all related modules? Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "</path/to/script>.py", line <number>, in <module>
    wn = turtle.screen()
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'screen'
```

because the turtle library doesn't have an attribute `screen`, but this is just a minor typo as the turtle library **does** have a `Screen` attribute. The Python programming language cares about the case of letters, which is often described as *case-senstive syntax* or [*case sensitivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity).